# PostgreSQL Database size is not equal to sum of size of all tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am using an AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance. I am using below query to get size of all databases.

```
SELECT datname, pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(datname))
from pg_database
order by pg_database_size(datname) desc
```

One database's size is 23 GB and when I ran below query to get sum of size of all individual tables in this particular database, it was around 8 GB.

```
select pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_total_relation_size(table_schema || '.' || table_name)))
from information_schema.tables
```

As it is an AWS RDS instance, I don't have rights on pg_toast schema.
How can I find out which database object is consuming size?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE) says:

> `pg_total_relation_size` ( `regclass` ) → `bigint`
>
> Computes the total disk space used by the specified table, including all indexes and TOAST data. The result is equivalent to `pg_table_size + pg_indexes_size`.

So TOAST tables are covered, and so are indexes.

One simple explanation could be that you are connected to a different database than the one that is shown to be 23GB in size.

Another likely explanation would be materialized views, which consume space, but do not show up in `information_schema.tables`.

Yet another explanation could be that there have been crashes that left some garbage files behind, for example after an out-of-space condition during the rewrite of a table or index.

This is of course harder to debug on a hosted platform, where you don't have shell access...

Comment: I was connected to same database, I cloned this database using `Create Database ...with template` command and new database had same size. As of now, i have taken dump of this database and created new database and dropped old one. This has reduced size to almost 7 GB.